# jquery addClass IE7 Performance Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I am facing a strange scenario only in IE7 like,
adding a class to an ID.

```
$(idName).addClass("sel");
```

If my `idName` is short then I am not facing any issue but if it is very long then browser is hanging.

At the time of hanging, `idName` is like `dateRange(2006,2007,2008,2009,2010)`

***Edited:***

```
populatedID = "dateRange(2006,2007,2008,2009,2010)";
var idName = "li[id=\"" + populatedID + "\"]";
$(idName).addClass("sel");
```

Please suggest me any alternative to work with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try caching the result of `$(idName)`? (Assuming it's not an element that's created dynamically.)

Comment: @Inerdia: Nope. there are some problems with caching with the dynamic data, So I am not caching it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "idName is like dateRange(2006,2007,2008,2009,2010)". Could you provide more information

Comment: Have you tried `$(document.getElementById(populatedID)).addClass("sel")`?

Comment: yes, but I need to add the class to idName only.

Comment: Hmmm, I've never used IDs before with parenthesis and commas before, but I would half guess that it's not good. They may interfere with the JQuery selector. It looks like you are trying to hijack the element Id to store data. This is wrong. Perhaps you could post a high level overview of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: that is an odd looking ID which would equate to id="dateRange(2006,2007,2008,2009,2010)" if it were in-line and thus invalid as ID can consist of only alpha numeric plus "-" and "_" and begin with an alpha.

Comment: Agree, but how come working in IE8 and FF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is an odd looking ID which would equate to `id="dateRange(2006,2007,2008,2009,2010)"` if it were in-line and thus invalid as ID can consist of only alpha numeric plus "-" and "_" and begin with an alpha

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Answer (score 2):

One possible problem is that you're using characters that are not strictly permitted in IDs. While it may work in some browsers, you can't count on it -- especially in a browser as old as IE7.

As an experiment, perhaps you can try modifying these IDs, replacing the parentheses and commas with underscores and hyphens.

If you're using the ID to store data, a far better option is to use the [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function. When generating the HTML, stash your date ranges like this:

```
<li data-daterange="2006,2007,2008,2009">Something</li>
```

Then make a function to apply your styling logic like this:

```
var highlightYear = function (year) {
  $('#your_ul').find('li').filter( function(){
    return $.inArray( year, $(this).data('daterange').split(',') ) > -1;
  }).addClass('sel');
};
```

Then use:

```
highlightYear( 2006 ); 
// adds "sel" class to all LI elements with "2006" in "daterange"
```

References: [**W3C HTML Specification on name and ID tokens**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id).

Answer (score 1):

i have never seen an id with

```
(,)
```

can you try using alphanumerics and seperate with hyphens or underscores or camelcase?